# Remove characters from variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript

My variable looks as following:

`response = "{ tradeofferid: '63341523' }"`

I would like to remove all characters except for the letters and the semicolon.

I tried using the replace function but I get some errors.

```
  function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    var result = response;

    result = result.replace(/[{}]/g, "");

    console.log(offerStatus);

    res.end(result);

  });
```

My console points at replace and the error log says: undefined is not a function

What I want to end up with is

```
response = "tradeofferid: 63341523"
```

Comment: `response = tradeofferid: 63341523` is not valid javascript. Unless you just want that as a string?

Comment: It sounds like you're actually asking how to use Javascript objects.

Comment: When you declare response = { tradeofferid: '63341523' }, It becomes object. Its not a string anymore, So if you want to format it then you should retrieve the value (by response.tradeofferid) first and then format it.

Comment: @Arpit Parasana That solved it and directly gives me the correct value. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response = { tradeofferid: '63341523' };
alert(response.tradeofferid);

for(var name in response) {
    alert(name);
    var value = response[name];
    alert(value);

}

responseString = name + " : " + value;
alert(responseString);
```

You may try this but this answer is only specific to your question. This will not work if you have more than one attributes in "response" object.

Answer (score 1):

```
response = "tradeofferid: " + JSON.parse(response)[tradeofferid]
```

... if you really want a string for display or something, but I'm guessing you actually just want to parse the JSON and pass the object around but haven't realized it yet.

Comment: That turns it into response = "[object object]"

Comment: Oh, so you're starting with an object, not a JSON string like you said in your question.  You meant "response = { tradeofferid: '63341523' }"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set something to be replaced in the `.replace` method. Try with:

```
var result = response.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\: ]/g, "")
```